# Return random rows from database without repeating

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a quiz where I stored in a table questions and each time one question is asked I want another question to show. I have tried using `rand()`:

```
select * from quiz order by rand() LIMIT 1
```

but the rows are being repeated.

Is there anything else I can use where I can get random rows but without getting same questions again?

Comment: For how long must they not repeat? Is there a limited number of questions? Do you want your user to go through all questions in the database once before seeing a duplicate?

Comment: From performance point of view is in general bad idea to use ORDER BY RAND() statement. Anyway if you want to use it, just add grouping in your query, for example GROUP BY quiz_id or some other unique identifier in order to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: yes i want the user to go through all questions once

Comment: Then just select all data a shuffle the results with php.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sessions and your quiz id.

For example

```
select * from quiz order by rand() LIMIT 1
```

add in session quiz the quiz id:

```
if(!$_SESSION['quiz']) { $_SESSION['quiz'] = array(); }
$_SESSION['quiz'][] = $row['id'];
```

and call NOT IN:

```
$session = implode(", ", $_SESSION['quiz']);
$query = "select * from quiz WHRE `id` NOT IN (".$session.") order by rand() LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `id` of the previous returned row and exclude it from future queries.

```
select * from quiz WHERE id NOT :previous_id order by rand() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you require the user to go through all questions once in a random order, you'll have to keep track of an individual "playlist" for each user. Preferably using sessions:

```
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['ids']) {
    $_SESSION['ids'] = $db->getAllQuestionIdsFromTheDatabase();
                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    // Leaving this up to you.

    shuffle($_SESSION['ids']);

    // $_SESSION['ids'] should now look like array(42, 12, 75, ...);
}

$question = $db->getQuestionById(array_shift($_SESSION['ids']));
...
```

You can do the randomization either in the database using `ORDER BY RAND()` or in PHP using `shuffle`, either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could select all the rows (or some of them) and use [`shuffle()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) mainly because `ORDER BY RAND()` is really resource *unfriendly* and it actually re-queries each row of your table, assigns a random number ID and then delivers the results.